# Ubuntu 21.10 Screen Lock

Tags: lock-screen, 21.10

Can't log back in after screen lock on Ubuntu 21.10. Worked fine on prior version.  Any solution or workaround?  Running Ubuntu on a Dell Inspiron 17-5765. Upgraded from 21.04. Tried Ctrl-Alt-Del as suggested. Nothing.

Comment: What happens exactly?

Comment: After screen locks, can only get a blank screen. Clicking or touching a key brought back login screen in prior version.  Forced to reboot.

Comment: what happens if you do `Ctrl+Alt+Del`? For reference, it works fine for me using a Live USB by moving the mouse. What was your previous version? Please [edit] your question with answers to queries - do not add to the comment trail which is there for asking you questions.